# Loop page with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would scraper urls of player of all pages from this website https://www.transfermarkt.it/detailsuche/spielerdetail/suche/27564780
but I can scrape only the first one, why?
I write a cicle for with range()

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


list_url=[]
def get_player_urls(page):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
    }
    link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.it/detailsuche/spielerdetail/suche/27564780/page/{page}'
    content = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    for urls in soup.find_all('a', class_='spielprofil_tooltip'):
        url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.it' + urls.get('href')
    
        print(url)
        list_url.append(url)
        
    return

for page in range(1,11,1):
    get_player_urls(page)

df_url = pd.DataFrame(list_url)
df_url.to_csv('df_url.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: You don't use `page` argument now, because link isn't formatted as you expect. Prefix it with f to do what you want: `link = f'example.com/page/{page}'`. Without this prefix your {page} part is just a string and isn't substituted by parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually imputing the page into the url. Also, no need to put return on your function. You aren't returning anything:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


list_url=[]
def get_player_urls(page):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0"
    }
    link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.it/detailsuche/spielerdetail/suche/27564780/page/{page}'.format(page=page)   #<-- Add this
    content = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    for urls in soup.find_all('a', class_='spielprofil_tooltip'):
        url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.it' + urls.get('href')
    
        print(url)
        list_url.append(url)

for page in range(1,11,1):
    get_player_urls(page)

df_url = pd.DataFrame(list_url)
df_url.to_csv('df_url.csv', index=False, header=False)
```